# What were the biggest events in terms of Monetary Policy in May 1975?

Tags: inflation, monetary-policy, federal-reserve, yield-curve

Take a look at this plot, which is the daily American zero-coupon yield curve from 1975, as reconstructed by Liu and Wu (JFE, 2021):
[image]

One can see a major change of shape in May, 1975. It seems that the important day was 14-15th May, 1975. I took a look on what happened that day and found no answer to explain such a big movement. There was a FOMC meeting during that month, but I believe it happened in the 20th.

Any ideas on what happened here?